# Firebase: restrict a child's write access to browser session that created it

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

How can I restrict the write access to an object's property in Firebase to the browser session that created it using `ref.push()`? I want all clients to have read access to children of `/buttonClicksByBrowserSession` as I do in the security rules below, and I want clients to be able to push a child to `/buttonClicksByBrowserSession` and edit it, but I want edits to that child to be disallowed after browser refresh.

**My Firebase security rules:**

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false,
        "buttonClicksByBrowserSession": {
          ".read": true,
          "$autoGeneratedID": {
            ".write": "newData.isNumber() && (data.val() == null && newData.val() === 1 || newData.val() - data.val() === 1")
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**My JS:**

```
var fbRef = new Firebase('https://fbKey.firebaseIO.com/buttonClicksByBrowserSession');
var numClicksRef = fbRef.push();
var numClicks = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    numClicksRef.set(++numClicks);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize [anonymous login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-anonymous.html), which allows for you to assign users a per-session, unique id that can be used in security rules.

```
var fb = new Firebase(URL);
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(fb, function(err, user) {
   if( err ) throw err;
   if( user ) init(user);
});

function init(user) {
   fb.child('buttonClicksByBrowserSession/'+user.uid).transaction(function(currValue) {
      return (currValue||0)+1;
   });
}

auth.login('anonymous', {rememberMe: false});
```

Security rules:

```
"buttonClicksByBrowserSession": {
    ".read": true,
    "$autoGeneratedID": {
       ".write": "auth.uid === $autoGeneratedID",
       ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() === (data.val()||0)+1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality I think I'd do a simple logout/login in the page initialization - get a new user id each refresh.

Then hold the data with the userid as the final key, with a rule to restrict writes to the user with that id...